# Multiply array value by number

Tags: php

Im getting the price from array by key.
Then I try to multiply : $count by $price.

```
foreach ($count_value_per_country as $country_code => $country_count){
        $price_per_country = $international_price[$country_code];
        $price = $country_count * $price_per_country;

        echo "Count: ".$country_count."<br> Price: ".$price_per_country."<br><br>";
    }
    

print_r("Final Price: ".$price);
```

I got this return
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMiHi.png)

That not take all $count * price, only the last..
Thanks you and sorry for my english.

Comment: If you're looking for a total, then change `$price =` to `$price +=`

Comment: thanks you my friend :)

Comment: Glad I could help!